# Google App Engine: API is not being called in deployed version

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-app-engine, google-maps-api-3, google-app-engine-python

I am building a web app with Google AppEngine. I am using the Google Maps, Google Places, and Geocoding API's.

In the local version, everything works as it should. When the page is loaded, the user's current location is indicated and all the nearby stores are marked with markers on the map that appears on the webpage.

In the deployed version, only the map loads. I checked the console developer's log on Google and I noticed that a request to the Google Maps API is made, but not to the Google Places or Geocoding API's. I'm really confused/not sure what's going on. I tried browsing through some old questions, but I can't figure out how to fix this. If anyone could offer a solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

** I have made sure that the deployed version is the most recent version. It 100% works on localhost, but doesn't on the deployed webpage.

Edit: the API's aren't being called because they don't work on "insecure origins". I've configured the app.yaml under handlers to be

```
- url: /.* 
script: IGNORED 
secure: always
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: People, STOP voting to close questions that you don't understand!

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Understanding a question is not a requirement for voting to close a question (after all one of the closing reasons is "unclear what you're asking"). But in this case IMHO it's off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. This one has no code, no logs/errors, nothing but a story which could have a variety of reasons behind it. Inviting guesswork.

Comment: @DanCornilescu: This is a question from a user who is new to SO. At the very least, a polite thing is to explain how a question can be improved. We want a polite community here, right? :)  Also, the votes to close were because the question is "not about programming", which is not true.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin ohhh thank you! There's a warning that states that some functions I've called no longer work on "insecure origins". There's also an uncaught reference error, but it doesn't show up on the log in my local version. And I am so sorry I didn't include any code in my question, I honestly didn't think it was necessary because my problem occurred after I deployed my app.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I agree, I often add comments, but sometimes I fail to. My bad. As for "not about programming" - unfortunately that's the umbrella category under which several reasons (including the one I mentioned) are grouped.

Comment: @sleepy No worries, no appologies necessary. We all make mistakes, what's important is to learn from them :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to separately call Google Places and Geocoding APIs. All those are included in the Google Map API. If you want to choose on what you should include in your map [click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/style-reference) to refer the API on customizing your map.

Comment: On App Engine you have to enable those APIs separately in the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Google App Engine doesn't support secure connections, which both the Geolocation & Google Places API's need, in order to be called. However, Google App Engine can support secure connections. The local host does support secure connections, which is why the local version of my app was working.

To properly support secure connections after deploying the app, just add in the parameter "secure: always" in the app.yaml file under Handlers!